# ignore files with db.zip and copy remaing file in a folder in linux

Tags: linux

I want to ignore files with _db.zip in a folder and copying remaining zip files in a folder in linux.

I have tried as below:

```
for filename in *;
do 
  extension="${filename#*.}"  ====> giving output as 33_adc_db.zip  
  where here i want output as db.zip
 
  if [ "$extension" != .zip]; then
    echo ""
  fi
```

Please help me on this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

in one line :

```
# full path to source dirs
l_src=~/src
# full path to target dirs
l_tgt=~/tgt

find $l_src -type f ! -regex ".+_db\.zip" | xargs -I "{}"  mv {} $l_tgt
```

each command in [details](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20%24l_src%20-type%20f%20%21%20-regex%20%22.%2B_db%5C.zip%22%20%7C%20xargs%20-I%20%22%7B%7D%22%20%20mv%20%7B%7D%20%24l_tgt%20)

1. -type f -- get files only
2. ! -regex ".+_db.zip" -- not like "_db.zip". ".+" -- any char "\." -- treat as dot not like any char
3. xargs -I "{}" -- use symbol "{}" as stdin and get line by line
4. try this for better understanding `find $l_src -type f ! -regex ".+_db\.zip" | xargs -I "{}" echo "mv {} $l_tgt"` here we just echo commands

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to get the extension of the filename, but in order to use a variable, you need to preceed it with a dollar-sign:

Instead of:

```
extension="${filename#*.}"
```

Try:

```
extension="${$filename#*.}"
```

Is it going better?

**Edit:** you might also add an extra space before closing the bracket in your `if`-clause:

```
if [ "$extension" != .zip ]; then
```

Comment: also needs a space before closing `]` imho

Comment: it showing below error 

-bash: ${$filename#*.}: bad substitution

Answer (score 0):

I created a few files using touch `touch a.zip  b.zip  bash  c.x.zip`
And run this simplified bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *;
do 
  extension="${filename##*.}"
  echo "${filename}"
  echo "${extension}"
  if [ ${extension} != ".zip" ]; then
  echo "hello"
  fi
done
```

To get

```sh
a.zip
zip
hello
b.zip
zip
hello
c.x.zip
zip
# no hello for c!
```